# Incorrect syntax on icon tag in manifest?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been trying to create a chrome extension but when I try and link to the icon files it just says that there is a syntax error in the manifest file (left side of image). I suspect is has something to do with white space because I copied the icon tags from a working extension and changed the file names and it is still not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://imgur.com/a/s7SOQ

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `,` after your `"version_name"`.